# How to get current timestamp in string format in Java? "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

How to get timestamp in string format in Java? "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Timestamp());
```

This is what I have, but Timestamp() requires an parameters...

Comment: preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Replace

```
new Timestamp();
```

with

```
new java.util.Date()
```

because there is no default constructor for [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), or you can do it with the method:

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and `java.sql.Timestamp` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I used:
`new Date().getTime();`

Answer (score 236):

Use `java.util.Date` class instead of Timestamp.

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
```

This will get you the current date in the format specified.

Comment: This helped me out and I made some changed so I don't have to import     `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date())`

Comment: Better `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())`;

Comment: SimpleDadeFormat is not thread safe, make sure you are not using it in multithreading environment. Once I overlooked this and it was giving unpredictable results when two dates were compared.

Answer (score 101):

## tl;dr

Use only modern *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible legacy classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
ZonedDateTime                    // Represent a moment as perceived in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region ( a time zone).
.now(                            // Capture the current moment.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )  // Specify the time zone using proper Continent/Region name. Never use 3-4 character pseudo-zones such as PDT, EST, IST. 
)                                // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
.format(                         // Generate a `String` object containing text representing the value of our date-time object. 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss" )
)                                // Returns a `String`.
```

Or use the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current default time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss" ) )
```

## *java.time* & JDBC 4.2

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes as seen above.

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Use [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)) and [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class)).

## Use java.sql only for drivers before JDBC 4.2

If your JDBC driver does not yet comply with JDBC 4.2 for support of *java.time* types, you must fall back to using the java.sql classes.

### Storing data.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

### Retrieving data.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

The java.sql types, such as [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), should only be used for transfer in and out of the database. Immediately convert to java.time types in Java 8 and later.

## `java.time.Instant`

A `java.sql.Timestamp` maps to a [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), a moment on the timeline in UTC. Notice the new conversion method [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant()) added to the old class.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … );
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

## Time Zone

Apply the desired/expected time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

## Formatted Strings

Use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to generate your string. The pattern codes are similar to those of [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but not exactly, so read the doc carefully.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss" );
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

This particular format is ambiguous as to its exact meaning as it lacks any indication of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone.

## ISO 8601

If you have any say in the matter, I suggest you consider using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than rolling your own. The standard format is quite similar to yours. For example:
`2016-02-20T03:26:32+05:30`.

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default, so no need to specify a pattern. The `ZonedDateTime` class extends the standard format by appending the name of the time zone (a wise improvement).

```
String output = zdt.toString(); // Example: 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

## Convert to java.sql

You can convert from java.time back to `java.sql.Timestamp`. Extract an `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime`.

New methods have been added to the old classes to facilitate converting to/from java.time classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: So what is The Right Way to get the current wall clock time stamp in format "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"?  Without explicitly specifying hard-coded string of my local time zone?  That's what topic starter was asking, and I could not find it in your answer...

Comment: @t7ko I added a line of example code to the *tl;dr* section showing how to ask explicitly for the JVM’s current default time zone. Calling `now()‘ without any arguments does the same but is not clear if you meant to use the default or if you were ignorant or forgetful about the crucial issue of time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque very compact and pure +1.

Answer (score 38):

Use modern `java.time` classes if you use java 8 or newer.

```
String s = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

---

Basil Bourque's answer is pretty good. But it's too long. Many people would have no patience to read it. Top 3 answers are too old and may mislead Java new bee .So I provide this short and modern answer for new coming devs. Hope this answer can reduce usage of terrible `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 32):

You can make use of java.util.Date instead of Timestamp  :

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime()
```

Result:

```
1539594988651
```

Comment: It doesn’t have the string format asked for. Also I’m afraid that the only thing it adds to a couple of similar answers, is needless complication…

Answer (score 7):

A more appropriate approach is to specify a Locale region as a parameter in the constructor. The example below uses a US Locale region. Date formatting is locale-sensitive and uses the Locale to tailor information relative to the customs and conventions of the user's region [Locale (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
```

Comment: No such thing as “Locale Zone”. I suspect your are confusing `Locale` and time zone which are unrelated. `Locale` controls the cultural norms for formatting and the human language used for name of month/day. The time zone adjusts the date-time representation to be appropriate to some region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time). In the case of this Question, Locale is irrelevant as there are no formatting issues with which to apply cultural norms nor are there any names of month/day to localize to any particular human language.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your input. I've updated the answer to be more explicit

Answer (score 2):

I am Using this

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(timeStamp);
```

Comment: This was the only answer, which I was actually able to use. I was able to find proper imports!

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following strategy.**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

Timestamp today = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Comment: It does not answer the question asked. And using the `Timestamp` class is not recommended. It’s a very poorly designed class and long outdated. Use java.time. See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520573/5772882).

Comment: Also it’s already proposed in two existing answers including the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

Those `java.util.Date` answers at the top need to go.  Here's some code I wrote that deals with different formats. It's also easier to go with a working example:

```
package com.brian.TimeZoneUtil;

import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class TimeZoneConversion {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            String inSlashDateString = "10/31/201100:00:00";
            String inHyphenDateString = "2011-10-31T01:01:01";
            String inEpochDateString = "1687170164410";

            DateTimeFormatter slashFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss");
            DateTimeFormatter hyphenFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            
            ZonedDateTime epochDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(inEpochDateString)).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Indiana/Indianapolis"));
            
            System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss").format( LocalDateTime.parse(inSlashDateString + "00:00:00", slashFormatter)));
            System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss").format( LocalDateTime.parse(inHyphenDateString, hyphenFormatter)));
            System.out.println(epochDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")));
            
                        
        }
}
```

Comment: No need to define this pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`. Already defined: [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).