# How to append a timestamp to the generated jar using gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar

How can I append a timestamp to the jar file name when running the `gradle build` command?

The jar name I have now:

```
abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What I actually want:

```
abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT20180721101136.jar
```

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.abc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

I've tried `build.date = '${timestamp}'`, but that doesn't work.
I've also tried `doFirst`, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily choose the name of the JAR file yourself by setting the `archiveName` property of the respective task:

```
jar {
    archiveName = 'myJarFile.jar'
}
```

By default, the `archiveName` will be assembled via the schema `[baseName]-[appendix]-[version]-[classifier].[extension]` where each part is another property of the respective task. For your specific use case I would suggest to just change the `version` part of the name:

```
jar {
    version = project.version + timestamp      // define timestamp in a way you like
}
```

You may want to put this configuration into a `doFirst` closure, as the timestamp will be more precise to the time the JAR file was actually created.

Comment: is timestamp a function that I need to define?

Comment: A variable, you can set it right before setting the new `version`. I don't know how you want to define the timestamp, you can use any method from the JDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068676/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-string-format-in-java-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss

Comment: Im doing like this : `def timestamp = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
jar {
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
 archiveName = 'abc' + version + timestamp
}` but it does not append version or timestamp to the jar

Comment: @user2340345 FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @user2340345 `String dateTimePortion = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss" ) ) ;`  Include the `T` in the middle to follow the popular standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values. And consider what wall-clock time you want to use for capturing the current moment (the time zone, or offset-from-UTC) – Usually best to work in UTC.