# Subtract 3 weeks from current timetamp

Tags: java, timestamp, sql-timestamp

How can I get the current timestamp - x number of weeks using java.sql.Timestamp;

This is my current timestamp `Timestamp.from(Instant.now(clock));`

x- could be any number from 0-5

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068676/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-string-format-in-java-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss

Comment: Doesn’t this answer your question? [How to subtract X day from a Date object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use either `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant`or `LocalDateTime`; all are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing the code provided, I would suggest to subtract the weeks from the `Instant` via [`Instant::minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#minus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). Since [`ChronoUnit.WEEKS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#WEEKS) is not supported by `Instant::minus`, we can convert the weeks in days by multiplying them with 7.

If changing the `Instant` is not an option, we could convert the `Timestamp` into an `Instant`, subtract, and convert back:

```
Timestamp.from(timestamp.toInstant().minus(x * 7L, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Ae2lUv)

Or, if you are a friend of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html)s:

```
Optional.of(timestamp)
    .map(Timestamp::toInstant)
    .map(t -> t.minus(x * 7L, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
    .map(Timestamp::from);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2UssO2)

Comment: Why does it giv me :
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Weeks

Comment: Timestamp.from(timestamp.toInstant().minus((line.hashCode() % 4) * 7L, ChronoUnit.WEEKS))

I still see UnsupportedTemporalTypeException. Here s the code I use

Comment: This answer assumes that a week is always 7 times 24 hours (168 hours), which isn’t always the case in real life, or more precisely, in real time zones.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Instant Directly example, using local time:**

```
Instant.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()).minus(numberOfWeeks * 7L, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

**Used in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant now = Instant.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
    System.out.println("The time right now (local time): " + Timestamp.from(now));

    long numberOfWeeks = 3L;
    Instant minusXweeks = now.minus(numberOfWeeks * 7L, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println("The time 3 weeks before now (local time): " + Timestamp.from(minusXweeks));
}
```

**Output:**

```
The time right now (local time): 2020-08-20 23:24:58.077223
The time 3 weeks before now (local time): 2020-07-30 23:24:58.077223
```

**NOTE:**

Why not use ChronoUnit.WEEKS directly? See below:

```
Instant.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()).minus(numberOfWeeks, ChronoUnit.WEEKS)
```

Seems like ChronoUnit.WEEKS is not supported by method java.time.Instant.minus while enum ChronoUnit.DAYS is. When using ChronoUnit.WEEKS in method java.time.Instant.minus then following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Weeks
at java.base/java.time.Instant.plus(Instant.java:861)
at java.base/java.time.Instant.minus(Instant.java:978)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:18)
```

Answer (score 1):

To subtract x weeks from the current time of the calendar, you can also try:

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, - (7 * no_of_weeks))