# Set date into object's field

Tags: java

I have a simple class Message and some fields. One of them is the String date. I want to set formatted

```
public class Message {
  Long id;
  String text;
  String date;
}
```

My goal is to set a formatted String of current date (Pattern is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX") while creating object Message. I can make new object by new or by @Bulder Lombok but how can i set string date ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068676/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-string-format-in-java-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current timestamp in string format in Java? "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068676/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-string-format-in-java-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss)

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your problem is. Usually the fields are made private and you have a constructor to set the fields during creation or setters for each field.

Comment: Problem is to set while creating object

Comment: Provide a parameterized constructor, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the pattern you provided, an `OffsetDateTime` would be my choice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OffsetDateTime nowWithOffset = OffsetDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(nowWithOffset);
}
```

This output (some seconds ago)

```
2020-09-18T10:55:02.832+02:00
```

As you can see, your desired pattern matches the default one used by an `OffsetDateTime`.

I would make the attribute `date` an `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `String` and provide a simple method for a `String` representation, maybe like this:

```
public String getDateAsString() {
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
}
```

and if you receive such a `String` and want to set your attribute, use a parameterized constructor or a setter / setting method, e.g.

```
public void setDateFromString(String date) {
    this.date = OffsetDateTime.parse(
                        date,
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
}
```

**and better replace the `y` in the pattern by a `u`, because a `y` could cause trouble in some situations where an era would be required.**

Answer (score -1):

```
class Message {
Long id;
String text;
String date;

public Message() {
    this.date = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

}

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.